# Conceptual workflow for python app API store data for reporting usage

Tags: python, api, fastapi, saas, conceptual

I am working on a small ml app, where some image can be uploaded and an estimation is given in return.
There will be 5 to 50 users and I need to **keep track of the usage** of these users to create monthly reports and maybe limit the usage to some amount (counter).
I am using fastapi and would like to know what would be a good pathway.

**Store the usage in SQL  ?**  Extra DB table for: user ID, usage count, filename, date

Or create one **nested list** with all the data for **all clients** and sort it out each month for each user .
list = [[ID, Date, Filename], […]]

Or create a **nested list for each customer** with ID, usage count, filename, date.
list_user_ID = [[Date, Filename], […]]

I am not sure what to do. SQL might be safe and provide nice API options but needs fancy SQL queries to set up the limit and extra DB requests in API ?
Lists are maybe good for setting up a limit direct in api with a counter function but need to be in memory when used ?

I have looked at many Fastapi APPs  but could not find a single one with this kind of monthly reporting. Most big APPs use stripe or other payment tools which I don’t need .

What is a common strategy for this concept. Any Idea or hints for me ?

Comment: I would 100% go with the database table. A python list only exists in memory, so whenever you need to restart your app (to update it, or because it crashed, or the server went down), you'll loose all your data. In general, web applications should be as stateless as possible.

Comment: Good point, it just irritates me I could not find an example app with SQLAlchemy models where API usage is stored. Guess the data is maybe pulled from logging or extra billing provider.

Comment: If you want to track every request, I would suggest looking into a [middleware](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/).

Comment: Will look into it, but looks tricky passing current user.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913998/how-to-get-current-active-user-in-middleware-fastapi-python) I will try with extra DB table. My littleDB with 50 users might get big with all the tracking info.